# cygwin sqlite3 backspace issue

Tags: sqlite, cygwin

I am trying to use sqlite3 in cygwin and I notice that the backspace key does not work. I am not able to delete the sqlite commands or edit them once typed. Pressing the backspace key prints <kbd>^H</kbd>. I remember using some commands to fix the issue. Does anyone know what it is?

Comment: Whatever terminal you are using isn't recognizing the backspace key. Usually it's a quirk with your terminal. Which Terminal are you using?

Comment: Thanks for replying. i am using cygwin rxvt-native

Comment: Backspace key works when I dont run sqlite3 commands

Comment: And the cygwin version of sqlite? [This SU post](http://superuser.com/questions/253059/using-sqlite3-with-cygwin) talks about other quirks people have had.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using the command 'stty erase ^H' fixed the issue.

Comment: Great! You'll want to put that in as your answer and accept it.

Comment: I did. Thanks! I dint have the permission to answer the question same day it was posted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command 'stty erase ^H' fixed the issue